# Need an analyzer that can split words by dot and reserve numbers

Tags: elasticsearch, analyzer

I want to split words by dot and reserve numbers, for example:
"google.com 123" => ["google", "com", "123"]

Standard analyzer can’t split words by a dot:
"google.com 123" => ["google.com", "123"]

Simple analyzer filter out the numbers:
"google.com 123" => ["google", "com"]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you know on which characters you want to split up tokens, you can use the [pattern tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-tokenizer.html). You can specify a regular expression to match all 'splitters'.

Comment: I don't exactly know the characters collection, pattern tokenizer may be a little complex.Now I replace '.' with '. ' before split words, and replace '. ' with '.' in view layer.

Comment: @CreateChen It's true that the pattern tokenizer may be too complex. If you only replace the dot, it may be worth to take a look at the [charfilter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-replace-charfilter.html). This is a preprocessing unit, where you could do the replacement. Then it would at least all be part of ES and not throughout your code.

Answer (score 0):

[It's quite late to answer the question, but may help others with similar problem.]

You can create a simple pattern split tokenizer with pattern regex based on your specifications.

```
{
  "analyzer": {
    "foo": {
      "tokenizer": "foo_tokenizer",
      "filter": ["lowercase"]
    }
  },
  "tokenizer": {
    "foo_tokenizer": {
      "type": simple_pattern_split",
      "pattern": "\\.| "
    }
  }
}
```

Sample query:

```
POST index_name/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "foo",
  "text": "google.com 123"
}
```

Result:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "google",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 6,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "com",
      "start_offset": 7,
      "end_offset": 10,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "123",
      "start_offset": 11,
      "end_offset": 14,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 2
    }
  ]
}
```